# Python Compare unequal data frames with text in true/false to get column output

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two data frames

df1

```
Animal         Categ_Class
--------------------------
Cat            Soft
Dog            Soft
Dinosaur       Hard
```

df2

```
Text                               Animal_Exist
-----------------------------------------------
The Cat is purring                  True
Cat drank the milk                  True
Lizard is crawling over the wall    False
The dinosaurs are extinct now       True
```

The column in df2 is derived from df1.Animal existing in df2.Text

I need help in understanding the code to write that I can get an output like this

Output

```
Text                               Animal_Exist   Categ_Class
--------------------------------------------------------------
The Cat is purring                  True          Soft
Cat drank the milk                  True          Soft
Lizard is crawling over the wall    False         NA
The dinosaurs are extinct now       True          Hard
```

I am new to python and have been trying this multiple ways since days.
Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Sure will keep this in mind. Sorry for the inconvenience. I was trying to put it as text but the table became unreadable. Can you please guide me how to publish this type of tables in stackoverflow. Appreciate your help.

Comment: So please convert picture to text versions of data

Comment: Can you please guide me how to show the tabular format of data in text.. I tried it first before taking image but was very unreadable.. Please guide.

Comment: Try it, I can help you. only paste, I can edit it after it.

Comment: All of your example text start with the name of the animal. Is this always true?

Comment: thanks a ton.. will do that right now :) Appreciate your help

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Not always.. this just for sample..

Comment: @jezrael Done as suggested.. Can you please help me format it?

Comment: @Yogi - How working my solution with real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get values of `Animal` converted to lowercase and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
import re

s = df1.assign(Animal = df1['Animal'].str.lower()).set_index('Animal')['Categ_Class']
pat = f'({"|".join(s.index)})'
cat = df2['Text'].str.extract(pat, expand=False, flags=re.I).str.lower().map(s)

df2 = df2.assign(Animal_Exist = cat.notna(), Categ_Class = cat)
print (df2)
                               Text  Animal_Exist Categ_Class
0                The Cat is purring          True        Soft
1                Cat drank the milk          True        Soft
2  Lizard is crawling over the wall         False         NaN
3     The dinosaurs are extinct now          True        Hard
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213842/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-python-compare-unequal-data-frames-with-text-in).